# How to achieve the Yelp Map Marker/Tooltip Effect in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, codeigniter

Ok so here's the deal,

I'm trying to display a tooltip (instead of the ginfowindow) over some Yelp Map Markers that I am pulling onto a Google Map.

I would like to have the exact same effects as Yelp. i.e. The tooltip seems to be set such that it's z-index is always above all other elements nearby, it moves the tooltip once it appears it is getting too close to the top of the page/bottom of the page, etc...

So far I have been able to get the z-index of the tooltip to appear correctly by appending the tooltip to the body (as opposed to the map). I thought I was on the right track but then I checked the implementation on a larger monitor and realized that the solution I had come up with was pushing the tooltips out too far right. See the code below:

```
    GEvent.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(){
        showMessage(this, infoWindowHtml);
    });

    GEvent.addListener(marker,'mouseout',function(){
        $("#tooltip").hide();
    });
/*
* Displays a Tooltip for the currently hovered marker
*/
function showMessage (marker, text) {
    var markerOffset = ymap.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPoint());

    theight = 20;

    twidth = 175;
    var twidth2 = $(".maincontent").width() + 12;

    $("#tooltip")
        .fadeIn()
        .html("<div class='content'>"+text+"</div>") 
        .css({ top: markerOffset.y - theight, left: markerOffset.x + twidth2 - twidth/2 })
        .appendTo("body");
}
```

Based on this code, does anyone see what I may be doing wrong with this tooltip implementation?

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired effect by appending to the body and finding the width of the user's window (via Javascript). After that, it was a matter of some simple math to remove/add the differences in browser widths to my tooltip's left CSS position.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is the best I could wrangle up.

Hopefully it helps you a bit Fvant?

```
/*
* Hide our tooltip DIV until a
* point has been hovered over 
* on the map
*/
$("#tooltip").hide();


/*
* Creates a marker for the given business and point
*/
function createMarker(biz, point, markerNum, category) {
    var infoWindowHtml = generateInfoWindowHtml(biz)
    var marker = new GMarker(point, yicon);
    marker.mycategory = category;

    yelpMarkers.push(marker);

    ymap.addOverlay(marker);

    GEvent.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(){
        showMessage(this, infoWindowHtml);          
    });

    GEvent.addListener(marker,'mouseout',function(){
        $("#tooltip").hide();
    });
```

}

```
/*
* Displays a Tooltip for the currently hovered marker
*/
function showMessage (marker, text) {

    var markerOffset = ymap.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPoint());
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();

    var theight = 20;

    //The twidth number below is half of our tooltip width.
    var twidth = 175;

    /*
    * The twidth2 number below is the width of the main content 
    * container area. Assumes a default window width of 1265
    */
    var twidth2 = 397;

    var extraPad;
    var tLeft;
    var tTop;

    // Setup our tooltip's width offset for different window widths
    if (winWidth > 1265) {
        extraPad = winWidth - 1265;
        tLeft = markerOffset.x + twidth2 + (extraPad/2);
    } 
    else if (winWidth < 1265) {
        extraPad = 1265 - winWidth;
        tLeft = markerOffset.x + twidth2 - (extraPad/2);
    }
    else { tLeft = markerOffset.x + twidth2; }

    // Setup our tooltip's height offset for different window height
    tTop = markerOffset.y - theight;

    $("#tooltip")
        .fadeIn()
        .html("<div class='content'>"+text+"</div>") 
        .css({ top: tTop, left: tLeft })
        .appendTo("body");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
* Displays a Tooltip for the currently hovered marker
*/

function showToolTip(marker,div_data)
{
    var my_div = "#bubble_container"; // div to show message
    jQuery(my_div).hide();   
    var markerOffset = map.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPoint());
    var  pos_map_cotainer= jQuery("#gmap_profile").position();   // getting position of map container
    var left_map_container = pos_map_cotainer.left;
    var top_map_container = pos_map_cotainer.top;
    var div_height = 115;  // height of message div
    var div_width = 378;   // width of message div
    var tLeft = (markerOffset.x + left_map_container)- div_width ;
    var tTop = (markerOffset.y + top_map_container) - div_height ;
    jQuery(my_div).html(div_data);
    jQuery(my_div).css({'left':tLeft,'top':tTop});
    jQuery(my_div).fadeIn(300);
}

function hideToolTip()
{
    jQuery("#bubble_container").fadeOut(300);
}
```